# Generated executable with GraalVM breaks with error "No awt in java.library.path"

Tags: graalvm

I'm trying to generate an executable Java Application using GraalVM 21.0.1 (actually tried some other versions as well) and getting this Exception once run it. The Application is neither Swing nor JavaFX but is using PrintLookupService which also uses `sun.awt.AppContext` and causes the missing library:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No awt in java.library.path
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.loadLibraryRelative(NativeLibrarySupport.java:136)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:106)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:916)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2059)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1384)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1382)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:129)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1381)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1419)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1393)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:595)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:273)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:262)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:129)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/sun.awt.AppContext.initMainAppContext(AppContext.java:262)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:315)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:298)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:129)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext(AppContext.java:297)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.getServicesForContext(PrintServiceLookup.java:96)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.getListOfLookupServices(PrintServiceLookup.java:110)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.getAllLookupServices(PrintServiceLookup.java:354)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.getServices(PrintServiceLookup.java:406)
    at java.desktop@21.0.1/javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(PrintServiceLookup.java:159)
```

This is how I generate the executable:

```
java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=META-INF/native-image -jar "myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

native-image --no-fallback -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=META-INF/native-image -jar "myapplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" "myapplication"
```

GraalVM recommends adding AWT using "[Reachability Metadata](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/ReachabilityMetadata.md)" in "[Tracing Agent](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/AutomaticMetadataCollection.md)" but I can't find where to specify it.

any help is highly appreciated.

**Update:**

I could successfully build and run native-image without above exception using [Liberica Native Image Kit from Bellsoft](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/native-image-kit/#downloads)
using this command:
`sdk install java 23.r20-nik`

The Problem is the generated image doesn't find a PrintService.

So I must still look for a Solution.

Comment: Which OS and arch you are using ?

Comment: And if you can share a reproducer it will be better

Comment: @OssamaIsmaili I have tested it on both Mac M1 and Linux with same result

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is still not resolved.
Check the issue status: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/4124
I suggest to find an alternative for fast startup (jlink is a good solution)